# Nearby cycles and tensor product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves

So suppose we have a projective smooth map $f: X \rightarrow A^1$.  Then we have a nearby cycles functor $\psi_f$ that sends constructible complexes on $X$ to complexes on $X_1$.  In general, I think this doesn't preserve tensor product, although I think there is a morphism 
$$\psi_f(E) \otimes \psi_f(F)  \rightarrow \psi_f(E\otimes F).$$

Does someone know under what conditions this map is an isomorphism?  Or some description of the cone?

Comment: Sorry, that should be X_0 not X_1.

Comment: Welcome to MO! Your question is a bit like asking when $H^*(X, E)\otimes H^*(X, F)\xrightarrow{\sim} H^*(X, E\otimes F)$ for two sheaves $E, F$ on a space/scheme $X$. In fact, it is asking precisely that for the restrictions of $E$ and $F$ to the "Milnor fibers" of $f$ at points of $X_0$. I therefore doubt there is a good answer.

Comment: Oh okay --- thanks!